# Background of RelativeLayout keep jumps and ducks

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-drawable

This is what exactly happens, The first screenshot is how it should be but most of the times when I start the activity, it starts like the second screenshot.

It only comes normal after I scroll up and down or focus in/out into some of the fields.

Can someone point out or give a fix to this issue?

**Note:** the logo is inside `@drawable/background` which is a jpg file for the whole screen

> **First:**

[image: Normal]

> **Second:**

[image: Ducked]

> **Xml Layout Code:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_un"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dip"
            android:text="Mobile #:"
            android:textColor="@color/newGrey"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_un"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_un"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/et_pw"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_un"
            android:background="@drawable/username_area"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLength="11"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/newGrey" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_pw"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_un"
            android:layout_below="@id/et_un"
            android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:text="Password:"
            android:textColor="@color/newGrey"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_pw"
            android:layout_width="270dip"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_pw"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_pw"
            android:background="@drawable/username_area"
             android:maxLength="30"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:password="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/newGrey" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_already"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_un"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_un"
            android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
            android:text="Account Login:"
            android:textColor="@color/newGrey"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_forgot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/et_pw"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Forgot Password? Click Here"
            android:textColor="@color/redish"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_LOGIN_in"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_forgot"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_LOGIN_in"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:text="Don&apos;t have an account?"
            android:textColor="@color/newGrey"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_LOGIN_in"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="Sign up now"
            android:textColor="@color/newGrey"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="Forgot Password? Click Here"
            android:textColor="@color/redish"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: LinearLayout is the worst thing i could do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never heard about this before but please try this out.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background" >
    </View>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_un"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dip"
        android:text="Mobile #:"
        android:textColor="@color/newGrey"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_un"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_un"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/et_pw"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_un"
        android:background="@drawable/username_area"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLength="11"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/newGrey" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_pw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_un"
        android:layout_below="@id/et_un"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:text="Password:"
        android:textColor="@color/newGrey"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_pw"
        android:layout_width="270dip"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_pw"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_pw"
        android:background="@drawable/username_area"
         android:maxLength="30"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:password="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/newGrey" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_already"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_un"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_un"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
        android:text="Account Login:"
        android:textColor="@color/newGrey"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_forgot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_pw"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Forgot Password? Click Here"
        android:textColor="@color/redish"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_LOGIN_in"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_forgot"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_LOGIN_in"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="Don&apos;t have an account?"
        android:textColor="@color/newGrey"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_LOGIN_in"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="Sign up now"
        android:textColor="@color/newGrey"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Forgot Password? Click Here"
        android:textColor="@color/redish"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Or you could try this.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background" >

        <ScrollView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/sc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_un"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="150dip"
                    android:text="Mobile #:"
                    android:textColor="@color/newGrey"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_un"
                    android:layout_width="200dip"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_un"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/et_pw"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tv_un"
                    android:background="@drawable/username_area"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLength="11"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/newGrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_pw"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_un"
                    android:layout_below="@id/et_un"
                    android:layout_marginRight="9dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                    android:text="Password:"
                    android:textColor="@color/newGrey"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_pw"
                    android:layout_width="270dip"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_pw"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tv_pw"
                    android:background="@drawable/username_area"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLength="30"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:password="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/newGrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_already"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_un"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_un"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
                    android:text="Account Login:"
                    android:textColor="@color/newGrey"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_forgot"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/et_pw"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Forgot Password? Click Here"
                    android:textColor="@color/redish"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_LOGIN_in"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_forgot"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:text="Login"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_LOGIN_in"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                    android:text="Don&apos;t have an account?"
                    android:textColor="@color/newGrey"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_LOGIN_in"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:text="Sign up now"
                    android:textColor="@color/newGrey"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:text="Forgot Password? Click Here"
                    android:textColor="@color/redish"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I need the `ScrollView` for the first one,already tried the second one but that distorts the logo and makes it look like a dwarf

Comment: For what purpose must the ScrollView be the first item? Have you tried setting the background on the ScrollView itself? Have you tried on a real device and if so which?

Comment: I have tried it on nexus s.I am currently in the process of making the xml a playground to more addition and deletions.. so all are invited for suggestion.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create an APK, upload it to for instance dropbox so I may try it live? It could be a bug in the phone.

Comment: Its spooked.. now its showing me red marks in each and every file!!

Comment: Do a clean. Project - Clean - Clean all projects if using Eclipse.

Comment: Everything got triggered by the fourth line in your second code.. instead of `android:background` you've written `ndroid:background`.. anyways trying to run now.

Comment: Look at that I forgot the 'a'.